# Sets, Total Functions, Equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have finite Sets $A$, $B$, $C$.

The function from $X \to_\text{total}Y$ represents a set of all of the total functions from set $X$ to set $Y$.

Ex:

> Suppose $X$ is the set $\{1,0\}$, $Y$ is the set $\{3,4\}$
>
> $X \to_\text{total}Y$ would be the set $\{(1,3)(0,3);(1,4)(0,4);(1,3)(0,4);(1,4)(0,3)\}$ which has four elements in it.

Now, the number of elements in $A\to_\text{total}(B\to_\text{total}$C)

will always equal the number of elements in $B\to_\text{total}(A\to_\text{total}$C).

(At least I think so, I tried with a few different sets by hand).

What is this property called?

It reminds me of the multiplicative property of equality but I don't think that's what it would be formally called, or if it is a property at all. I'm mainly looking for a better way to describe it than "I tried it on a bunch of different sets and it worked!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It represents one of the laws of exponents, that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.  The number of total functions from $X$ to $Y$ is $|Y|^{|X|}$ where the bars represent the cardinality of the set.  Then the first of your expressions is $\left( |C|^{|B|}\right)^{|A|}$ and the other is  $\left( |C|^{|A|}\right)^{|B|}$.  Both equal $|C|^{(|A||B|)}$

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I realized later that you can think of them as two different ways of looking at the set of functions from $(A \times B) \to C$.  One picks the first coordinate (from A) first, the other picks the second coordinate first.